# How do I store information in a variable name that contains a variable?

Tags: winforms, powershell

```
$DataApp2 = "SUCCESS FINALLY"
$Type = "App2"

$Data = Get-Variable -Name "Data$Type" -Value
Set-Variable -Name "Button$Type" -Value "$Data"
$ButtonName = Get-Variable -Name "Button$Type" -Value
$DefaultForm.Text = "$ButtonName"
```

as it may be more obvious now i intended to call a function that does something with nothing but the variables its given

seriously thank you [rokumaru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8523330/rokumaru) and [lotpings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings) you have no clue how much you have helped me

Comment: To have `$ButtonName` return `test` append the parameter `-Value` to `Get-Variable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Set-Variable` or `Invoke-Expression`.

```
Set-Variable -Name "Button$Type" -Value "test"
```

```
Invoke-Expression "`$Button$Type = 'test'"
```

but I recommend using a hashtable because it is safe and fast.

```
$h = @{}
$h."Button$Type" = "test"
$h.ButtonApp2
```

Comment: thank you it works perfectly i just implemented it dumbly